# In batch script, split only last string match in a variable

Tags: string, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, split

In a batch script, I need to split only the last string match in a variable in a loop until I no longer have the string match.

```
Input=Level1/Level2/Level3/Level4/LevelN
```

(where N can be any number)
Output:

```
Level1/LeveL2/Level3/Level4
Level1/LeveL2/Level3
Level1/Level2
Level1
```

I have tried the usual `"for /f "delims=/""` loops, but they only output each split of the input variable on an individual line. Besides, the value of "N" can vary. So I can't set the number of tokens to a certain value.

Please help.

Comment: You have not explained your task, there is no problematic code posted nor have you shown any string match. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54695966/edit) in order to bring it up to a sufficient standard to remain open and attract the responses you require. Also please note that Windows uses a backslash as a path separator, please ensure that you identify whether it is a forward or backward slash you're using as that separator.

Comment: What is the "match" that needs to be done? Is the "Output:" shown in the question the desired result?

Comment: Yes, the forward slash "/" is the string to be matched. The input is a reference to a folder structure within another tool (not a Windows path). The task is to script the removal of the last sub-string after the string match ("/") and execute a command on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This site don't works that way. You must post some code and explain the problems you have with it. In this way you can understand the changes made to your own code. If you request us for code, *any code*, then you could receive one ("any code") like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Input=Level1/Level2/Level3/Level4/LevelN"

:loop
   set "Output="
   set "part=%Input:/=" & set "Output=!Output!/!part!" & set "part=%"
   set "Input=%Output:~1%"
   if "%Input%" equ "~1" goto exitLoop
   echo "%Input%"
goto loop

:exitLoop
```

Comment: Thank you, @Aacini! This works for me. Sorry, for not posting my code, but as indicated, I had only tried the basic for-loop with "/" as a delimiter, hard-coding actual number for tokens, and then outputting it. Will do a better job posting next time! Thank you, all!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice recursive approach that makes use of the [`~` modifiers](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html), assuming that the input string is provided as a quoted (`""`) command line argument, which does not begin with `/`, does not contain two consecutive `//` and none of the characters `"`, `\`, `*`, `?`, `<`, `>`:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Store argument in variable:
set "INPUT=%~1"
if not defined INPUT exit /B
rem /* Precede with `\` and replace each `/` by `\`, so the resulting string appears to
rem    be an absolute path, which can be split by `~` modifiers of `for` variables;
rem    the inner `for` loop resolves the split path and removes any `\.` suffix: */
for %%I in ("\%INPUT:/=\%") do for %%J in ("%%~pI.") do set "REST=%%~pnxJ"
rem // Revert replacement of every `/` by `\` and remove the previously preceded `\`:
set "REST=%REST:\=/%"
set "REST=%REST:*/=%"
rem // If there is a string left, output it and call this script recursively:
if defined REST (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!REST!
    endlocal
    call "%~f0" "%REST%"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done with a regex in PowerShell. Since the regex is greedy be default, it will get everything up to the last SOLIDUS and store it in the $1 group.

```
SET "S=Level1/Level2/Level3/Level4/LevelN"

FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('powershell -NoL -NoP "'%S%' -replace '(.*/).*', '$1'"') DO (
    SET "RESULT=%%a"
)

ECHO RESULT is set to %RESULT%
```

Revision:

This outputs all groups and not just the last one.

```
SET "S=Level1/Level2/Level3/Level4/LevelN"

FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('powershell -NoL -NoP -Command ^
    "$a = '%S%'.Split('/'); " ^
    "for ($i = $a.Count - 2; $i -ge 0; $i--) { $a[0..$i] -join '/' }"') DO (
    ECHO %%a
)
```

Comment: Hi @lit, this worked for the first substring only (Output was Level1/Level2/Level3/Level4). I was looking for running it thru' a loop to get the other substrings, too. In any case, Aacini has answered the question above and I have accepted the answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @BS - I have added to the answer code that outputs all groups.

Answer (score 0):

A more classical approach, just for fun...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Input=Level1/Level2/Level3/Level4/LevelN"

rem Split the string, join it again and store partial results
set "aux="
set "n=0"
for %%a in ("%Input:/=" "%") do (
   set "aux=!aux!/%%~a"
   set /A n+=1
   set "out[!n!]=!aux:~1!"
)

rem Show results in reverse order
set /A n-=1
for /L %%i in (%n%,-1,1) do echo !out[%%i]!
```